# What could be driving a SyntaxError when trying to combine two columns to create dataframe names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am aiming to develop multiple dataframe names using two columns from my source dataframe as naming conventions for each col1 col2 combination .

For instance, if `period` and `dps` are columns in the source dataframe I want to create dataframes for each `period-dps` combination like so:

```
period = ['a','b','c']
dps = ['x','y','z']

for d in dps:
    for p in period:
        exec('{}{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(p,d))
```

This code works fine as tested, but when I incorporate my actual data I get a *SyntaxError: invalid syntax* error.

My question is what could be driving this error? Is there a possible issue with my original data I should review and clean first?

Thank you

Comment: In your real data, do `period` or `dps` contain characters that are illegal in variable names?

Comment: What's your actual data? Also, don't use `exec`. Store all your dataframes in a single list or dict, rather than trying to create variable names dynamically.

Comment: @JohnGordon I should have clarified this point. I reviewed my data as part of my troubleshooting and saw that it is entirely populated using only alphanumeric characters. This confused me because I couldn't see any issue which could cause a syntax error.

Comment: _populated using only alphanumeric characters_ Variable names can't start with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `exec`. Create a `dict` to store your dataframes.

```
period = ['a','b','c']
dps = ['x','y','z']

frames = {}
for d in dps:
    for p in period:
        frames[f'{p}{d}'] = pd.DataFrame()
```

You might also consider nested dicts.

```
from collections import defaultdict

frames = defaultdict(dict)
for d in dps:
    for p in period:
        frames[p][d] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
df_dict = {}
for p,d in zip(period,dps):
    name = p+d
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_dict[name] = df
```

This will return a dictionary of data frames, each named p+d and avoids using a nested for loop